# Python Regex, Match the last ip octet

Tags: python, regex, pcap, dpkt

i'm trying to match the last octet of an ip address but it doesn't work.

```
import dpkt
import socket
import re


def show_http_ip_info(pcap):
    for (ts, buf) in pcap:
        try:
            eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
            ip = eth.data
            src = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
            tcp = ip.data
            if tcp.dport == 80 and len(tcp.data) > 0 and src == '140.80.9.'+re.match(r"\d{0,3}", src):
                http = dpkt.http.Request(tcp.data)
                print('\nUser-Agent: ' + http.headers['user-agent'])
                print('Host: ' + http.headers['host'])
                print('Source IP: {}'.format(src))
                print('\n..........................')

        except:
            pass
```

am i missing something ??
Thanks for your help

Comment: Please specify `does not work`. Any errors? Also `re.match(...)` matches at the very beginning of a string - is this what you want? If not, use `re.search(...)` instead.

Comment: For me it seems like in your case `src == '140.80.9.'+re.match(r"\d{0,3}", src)` can be simplified to `src.startswith('140.80.9.')`

Comment: @Jan thanks for your comment!!

Comment: @Jan there is no error. it doesn't find anything